Cookies not being sent when user is redirected to a subdomain
After a successful login at the root domain ("http://localhost:3000"), users are redirected to a subdomain ("http://tenant1.localhost:3000/dashboard"). The server's redirect response (307) does include the cookies in the response header as expected. However, when the browser sends the new GET request to the subdomain URL (in response to the redirect), it doesn't include the cookies.
If I do a redirect to the root domain, the GET request does include the cookies.
I have tried every possible combination of cookie settings that I can think of (same-site, domain, secure, http-only, etc.) This is how it currently stands:
    cookies().set({
      name: 'access_token',
      value: access_token,
      httpOnly: false,
      domain: 'localhost',
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      maxAge: data.expires_in,
    });

I also tried to set the domain field in the cookie to things like ".localhost" and "tenant1.localhost". I must be missing something very basic...
This is a NextJS application.
Any ideas?
